# Week day and moment js

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I have this code:

```
var day = $("#date-filter").val();
```

The value of this input is: "22/03/2016".

I need week day.

I tried to do it in 2 ways but it does not work.

1) `moment(day).day()`

2) `moment($("#date-filter").val()).day()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment` works with dates and not strings. Before processing you need to parse your date string into `Date` object and only then pass it to `moment`:

```
var day = '22/03/2016', parsed = day.split('/');

moment(new Date(parsed[2], parsed[1] - 1, parsed[0])).day()
```

which returns 2 (actually, Tuesday). `- 1` is necessary here because JavaScript months start with 0.

Answer (score 3):

Moment's parser will handle this use case just fine, without needing to make any adjustments to the month part.

```
moment('22/03/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY').day()
```

It will even display the name of the week day for you if you like:

```
moment('22/03/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('dddd')
"Tuesday"
```

If you want the day of the week in a variety of languages, you can even do that. For instance, German:

```
moment('22/03/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY').locale('de').format('dddd')
"Dienstag"
```

See the parsing guide and the parsing docs for more info:
http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/